# Known Hosts file with mixed hashed and unhashed host names

Tags: ssh

Is a Known Hosts file with a mix of Hashed and Unhashed host names valid? Or must the host names in the file be all either Hashed or Unhashed?

Comment: What was the error `ssh` returned, when you tried it?

Comment: There was no error, I was just looking at a known_hosts file that had a mix of hashed and unhashed host names, and because of my noobishness didn't know if this was valid or not. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSH does not care if they are mixed. It is able to distinguish if the hostname is hashed or not. The option is mainly for storing the new known hosts.

Comment: Thanks, someone had removed an entry and I was confused when I had a look and there was a mix :)